# Events Python con Envio de datos a Ajax Server

Tags: python, ajax, variables

Buenas estoy tratando de capturar una varible en un .py que tengo que enviar de un capturador de controller PS4 a un servidor ajax como lo podría solucoionar¿?¿?

```
application = Flask(__name__)


@application.route('/update_decimal', methods=['POST'])
def updatedecimal():
    return jsonify('', render_template('random_decimal_model.html', x="variable a capturar"))

@application.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('home.html', x="random_decimal")


application.run()
```

En el otro python tengo esto

```
pygame.init()
application = Flask(__name__)
j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
j.init()
buttons = j.get_numbuttons()
_root_tit = "aawewq"
try:
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        vueltas = 0
        for event in events:
            if  j.get_axis(0) < -0.070:
                VariableaPasar= j.get_axis(0)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("EXITING NOW")
    j.quit()
```

Qué puedo hacer para pasar la variable j.get_axis(0) al servidor ajax de manera eficiente¿?

Comment: No veo nada claro lo que hace la parte flask, para empezar, pues la función `udpatedecimal()` se supone que recibe algo a través de POST, pero el código de la función no accede a ningún parámetro de la petición. Es más, retorna algo que no tiene sentido, que es la "jsonificación" de un html

Comment: Sea como sea, para pasarle algo a un backend flask basta usar el protocolo HTTP desde el otro script. Una forma muy sencilla es usar la librería requests. Tienes que hacer una petición POST a `http://ip.de.tu.backend.flask:5000/update_decimal`, aunque claro, se supone que algo tienes que enviar en el cuerpo del post pero no has especificado el formato del JSON en cuestión, ni puede deducirse del código que adjuntas

Comment: Por otro lado, ya que estás pasando un valor "constantemente" a través de un bucle, usar una petición POST separada para cada update es muy ineficiente. La solución más adecuada aquí sería usar websockets, pero eso es un asunto bastante complejo, especialmente si el backend es flask. Deberías quizás cambiarte a otro backend asíncrono con mejor soporte para websockets, como FastAPI o Sanic. Pero viendo que estos temas son más bien nuevos para ti, meterse en websockets puede ser excesivamente complejo, si bien sería lo más eficiente